# type="number" causing form field to shrink

Tags: ipad, html, safari

Using iOS 4.2.1 on iPad/iPhone, when I view a specific web page with type="number" for a text field, the text input space is slightly shorter than when it's type="text". And when I enter 3 digits, the first one gets cutoff, while it does not get cutoff with type="text". This problem does not happen on iOS 3.x on iPad/iPhone. The input field input area is identical, and it works fine.

Has anyone noticed this problem? Is there anything I can do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I also have this in the css file: .input {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

td.input input {
 width:45px;
}

Answer (score 1):

It's probably to do with the device browser's default style sheet. If you just apply styles the same styles to the text and number input fields it should render the same.

```
input[type=text], input[type=number] {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 1px 0;
    ...etc...
}
```

Comment: I added input[type=number] to all instances of the css file where input[type=text] is listed, and the same problem happens. I then added it directly to the html file: <input syle="width: 45; padding: 1px 0;" name="mname" type="text" value="" autofocus /> and the same problem happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the unit when styling width and height.

```
<input syle="width: 45px; padding: 1px 0;" name="mname" type="text" value="" autofocus />
```

or preferred:

```
input[type=number] {
width: 45px;
}
```